# How to load data into postgresql table having special characters in column names using copy_expert?

Tags: python, postgresql

I am loading a data from csv file emp.csv into postgres sql table- emp from the file as follows:

```
df = pd.read_csv("C:\Users\vgarud\emp.csv")
cols = ",".join(df.columns)
fh = open(r"C:\Users\vgarud\emp.csv",'r')
next(fh)
q1 = "copy public.emp(cols) from STDIN with (format csv,delimiter ',')"
cur.copy_expert(q1,fh)
con.commit()
fh.close()
```

This works fine. But whenever there is special charachters in the name of the any column like '-', copy query above fails.
It requires that columns should be wrapped with double quotes like this
"id","name","desgn","sal".

But this --> cols = ",".join(df.columns)  creates columns as "id,name,desgn,sal".

So any idea how to create quotes column name string from the dataframe columns ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The column names have to be wrapped in double quotes, which could be done that way:

```
cols = ",".join('"{}"'.format(col) for col in df.columns)
```